# How to install node modules in node js

Tags: node.js, angular

I have received a node js and angular project without node modules i need to install all packages which is mentioned in package.json file. kindly suggest the command to install node modules in both angular and node js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the **package.json** file in both projects (Angular and Node). And then run the install command.

> npm install

or

> npm i

Comment: after installed when i run npm start its showing js stack trace its created one json file.how to run this project...

Comment: in package.json file mentioned like this

"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host local.chekmarc.com",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "extractngx": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src/app --output ./src/assets/i18n/{en,es}.json --clean --format json",
    "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/cm-webapp/stats.json"
  },

how to run this project in localhost

Comment: @manikandan Just try simple `ng serve`

Comment: not working i have tried both ng serve and npm start

Answer (score 1):

Use "npm install" command

Answer (score 1):

yarn install or npm i or npm install